# How to run a set of commands on Konsole

Tags: plasma, konsole

How do i create a file/program that automatically opens my Konsole on startup and runs a set of commands all by itself? The OS i am using is Plasma Linux.

Comment: This is really vague. If you just need a commandline command to run you can write a shell script to execute the command, and then create a cronjob to execute the script at startup.

Comment: @greenpixel As I understand your question, you're asking how to cause a Konsole *window* to come up automatically when you log in, with particular commands running automatically in it. Am I right about this? Either way, I recommend you [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes. That is what i meant.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start normal Konsole window on startup, rather then create a file you should have use startup service (Autostart in plasma). Assuming you're running KDE, navigate to:

```
System Settings -> Startup & Shutdown -> Autostart -> Add Program..
```

Add following to field:

```
konsole -e --noclose command
```

Replace `command` with your desired command.

Comment: Place `--noclose` before `-e`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute commands on startup enable the rc.local file by typing

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

After that add every command you want to the following file
and they will be executed at startup

```
nano /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: This doesn't open a Konsole window upon user log-in. -1